# Structs into classes - Noticeable function overhead? C++

Tags: c++, function, methods, struct, overhead

Taking this as an example:

I have 20 structs. I access all of the struct's fields directly, getting values off them, pointers to other sub-structs they might have, etc.

Now, I restructure the program:
   Instead of acessing structs's fields DIRECTLY, I've encapsuled all of the struct into their own respective classes, and have functions for all the possible get(), and set(x).

The Question: Is there a performance impact for using methods/functions, instead of acessing structs directly?

Some sort of estimated % would be great, or some explanation.

Comment: Seriously, you don't want to be doing that egregious dereferencing, with or without the getters.

Comment: I think your question is a little vague.  It's not clear what your two examples mean, and its not clear what "significant" means because there's no context.

Comment: Getters and setters are often inlined by the compiler, meaning there will be no performance difference.

Comment: A better option would be to make as many getters/setters as inline functions (if possible). That way you will not loose the abstraction and performance.

Comment: No, you're not going to get very useful answers unless you give more specific examples (like maybe some classes/code examples that can be compiled).  Probably the best answer would be for you to just try doing some performance testing of the two alternatives yourself.

Comment: I estimate 0% speed difference in a release build, assuming you've made the accessor functions inline-able.

Comment: I didn't know of inline functions! That's a great thing to know about, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there shouldn't be a performance difference if the getters and setters are defined inline within the class.  For virtually any contemporary compiler, the function call will be expanded inline, leaving no overhead.  This will often be true for various small inline functions.  (See, for example, http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm, where Herb Sutter discusses why making most/all virtual functions nonpublic adds no overhead to the resulting code.)

Note that if you do define the function inline in the class, any client code will need to be recompiled if the definition ever changes.  But that applies to most/all changes in header files.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't heard of performance as a considerable difference between structs and classes, so it is your call. 
I googled these pages below, and they say there shouldn't be a difference when it comes to performance.
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/115725-is-a-struct-faster-than-a-class/
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?332571-Struct-vs-Class

Comment: My question was specifically if using functions over acessing the members directly had a performance impact, I'd searched around for that already, but thanks :)